# How to get the width of the gap actually produced in the output-file due to \hskip?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, tex-core, glue

How to get the width of the gap actually produced in the output-file due to `\hskip`?

I wonder if there is a way in Knuthian TeX of getting the width of the gap actually produced in the output-file due to `\hskip`?

I tried with `\lastskip` but seems that does not get you the width of the gap actually produced but does get you what the `\hskip`-directive looked like:

```tex
\newskip\scratchskip

\noindent This is the textwidth:

\smallskip

\noindent\hrule

\smallskip

\hfill These are 2cm: \leaders\hrule\hskip 2cm \null

\hfill These are 4cm: \leaders\hrule\hskip 4cm \nobreak\hskip 2cm \null

\noindent
This is the width of the gap produced by the
{\tt\string\hskip}-directive:

\noindent
\nobreak \leaders\hrule\hskip 4cm plus 1 fill
\nobreak \kern 2cm \null 

\noindent
This is the width of the {\tt\string\vbox}:

\noindent
\nobreak \hskip 4cm plus 1 fill
\scratchskip=\lastskip
\llap{\vbox{\hsize=\scratchskip \hrule\hfill}}%
\nobreak \kern 2cm \null 

\smallskip

\noindent
Seems {\tt\string\lastskip} gets you what the preceding
{\tt\string\hskip}-directive looked like and that at
specifying the width/\hskip0pt {\tt\string\hsize} of the
{\tt\string\vbox} the {\tt plus}-part (and the {\tt minus}-%
part if present) of that directive is ignored.

\noindent
Seems {\tt\string\lastskip} does not get you the width of
the gap actually produced due to the preceding
{\tt\string\hskip}-directive---otherwise the
{\tt\string\vbox} would have a larger width and reach the
left margin of the text.

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: You want the `\vbox`'s `\hsize` to be the width of the gap produced by the `\hskip`-directive "`\hskip 4cm plus 1 fill`"?

Comment: @UlrichDiez Yes.

Comment: If it was about LaTeX, you could use TikZ and save coordinates at the start and at the end of the gap as I did in the coding-examples at [https://groups.google.com/g/de.comp.text.tex/c/IDJG-9NWQjk/m/TTM-Bry3AAAJ](https://groups.google.com/g/de.comp.text.tex/c/IDJG-9NWQjk/m/TTM-Bry3AAAJ).

Comment: `\lastskip` gets you the glue node: that is, a node equivalent to `4cm plus 1 fill` but a glue node retains its stretch you can unbox and rebox to a different size and it will re-stretch, at no point other than finally writing out the dvi file does tex  calculate the actual size so that size is never saved in any programatically accessible way

Comment: Just out of curiosity, may I ask what the real application of this is?

Comment: @mickep No real application. ;-) I don't use tools for attempting "real work" until I have mastered them. Before attempting "real application" I want to have learned how TeX works/how to do things with TeX. I am in senior high school; no one in my surroundings uses TeX/LaTeX. I dream of making it to university and studying maths. I heard about TeX and LaTeX from university students who have the problem of being supposed to write papers with TeX/LaTeX without knowing how to use TeX/LaTeX. I don't want to come into such a situation. Since there is a lot to learn, I started with the TeXbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the information from the log, and in some controlled cases where you know in advance everything in a box so can deduce the glue by subtracting known lengths. But in general *by design* this information is inaccessible. For example Knuth writes in `tex.web`

> When TeX 'packages' a list into a box, it needs to calculate the
> proportionality ratio by which the glue inside the box should stretch
> or shrink. This calculation does not affect TeX's decision making,
> so the precise details of rounding, etc., in the glue calculation are not of critical importance for the consistency of results on different computers.

So (unlike box widths that are calculated with exact integer calculations in scaled points, and accessible to tex macros) glue stretch is allowed to use floating point but is not accessible.